# Determine what is Facebook URL for

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I have a project in which we have to enter a Facebook URL, after submitting the URL we have to determine if this URL is for a personal profile or a public page.

the URL of personal profile and public pages have the same structure for example:

personal profile:
https://www.facebook.com/zuck

public page:
https://www.facebook.com/cnn

so I need a programmatically way using HTTP request or whatever possible to figure it out what is this link for.

I tried doing that with Facebook graph API but I couldn't find out how.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Using the API is the only allowed way to programmatically interact with them. And yes you are right. You can't do it using the API.

Comment: so then how I can do it I saw other website can do that so there is a way

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible. I said Facebook doesn't allow it. So if you get banned don't be surprised.